# jquery .attr() only working in chrome?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Does anybody know why this code only works in chrome? I want to add more than one slider and I'm beginning to experiment by manipulating them based on their ids!

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >



</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){

    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    panel = "#panel"+currentId;

    $(panel).slideToggle("slow");

  });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
div.panel,p.flip
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#e5eecc;
     border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.panel
{
    height:120px;
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="panel" id="panel1">
<p>Because time is valuable, we deliver quick and easy learning.</p>
<p>At W3Schools, you can study everything you need to learn, in an accessible and handy format.</p>
</div>

<p class="flip" id="1">Show/Hide Panel</p>


<div class="panel" id="panel2" >
<p>Because time is valuable, we deliver quick and easy learning.</p>
<p>At W3Schools, you can study everything you need to learn, in an accessible and handy format.</p>
</div>

<p class="flip" id="2">Show/Hide Panel</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At a minimum, you can't use "2" as an ID, which might not be your problem but it's a place to start.

Comment: This code works fine for me in Chrome, FF, and IE8 (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/mAG7B/). Although I should state that JSFiddle does not offer jQuery 1.4.2, so it's using jQuery 1.4.4. Perhaps an update to your jQuery framework is in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I would not even mess around with finding a DIV based on adding numbers to the ID, it just seems to be an overly complex way of doing things Why not just nest the panels to be shown on click of the flip

http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/b6RkH/3/

And your Code did work in all the browsers i tested using the newest version of jquery

Comment: Okay, i will download the latest version of jquery!! Thanks for the sample!!

Comment: Hey any idea why this might not be working? I am going to write a lot of divs so i dont want to write every single one i want to create them like this but the function does not hide and show.$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".flip").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
    var p = $('<p></p>').addClass('flip').text('click here');
 var div = $('<div></div>').addClass('panel').text('hellow world');
    p.append(div);
    $("#preguntas").append(p);

    
});

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").bind('click',function(){
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    var panel = "#panel"+currentId;
   $(panel).slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
</script>
```